# Handlebars and textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, handlebars.js, mustache

I am trying to learn handlebars for use in my MVC app. I have the following in my template:

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="EmailHtml">Html:</label>
<div class="controls">          
<textarea id="EmailHtml" name="EmailHtml" cols="36" rows="5"/>          
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the JSON:

```
{"data":{"Results":[{"EmailHtml":"xyz"}],"Name":"Test Business"}}
```

After executing the above I see a TextArea with the correct width and height, but I don't see any data in it.

I also tried inserting the `value="{{this.EmailHtml}}"` but it still doesn't work.

How I get the textarea to be populated in my template?

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't that be something more like:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="EmailHtml">Html:</label>
  <div class="controls">          
    <textarea id="EmailHtml" name="EmailHtml" cols="36" rows="5">{{EmailHTML}}</textarea>          
  </div>
</div>
```

The value of a `<textarea>` is not in a `value` attribute, but resides between the tags. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7 , http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html , among others.

Comment: I can confirm @artlung answer. I just ran into the same issue myself. When I use `<textarea id="description" value="{{description}}" name="description" cols="36" rows="5"></textarea>`, nothing gets rendered inside the input field. But if I place the variable between `<textarea></textarea>` it works.

Answer (score 0):

With Handlebars you will want to use the unbounded helper so that you don't get the Handlebars marker elements inside your textarea.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="EmailHtml">Html:</label>
    <div class="controls">          
        <textarea id="EmailHtml" name="EmailHtml" cols="36" rows="5">{{unbound EmailHTML}}</textarea>          
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference: [Handlebars basics](http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_handlebars-basics)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are keeping the handlebar html template in a variable tpl and the data in another varible. And then you're writting:-

```
HandleBars.compile( tpl )(data)
```

The in the handlebar template you've to write :-

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="EmailHtml">Html:</label>
<div class="controls">          
    <textarea id="EmailHtml" name="EmailHtml" cols="36" rows="5">{{ data.Results.[1].EmailHtml}}</textarea>          
</div>
</div>
```